# IOS: Search algorithm with proper GCD code

Tags: ios, multithreading, search, grand-central-dispatch, background-process

I made my search algorithm for my UISearchBar, and I know that I must search in a background thread. Honestly I'm not familiar with multi-threading, so I'm looking for help. I'm using GCD (Grand Central Dispatch).

Here is my code, I want to know is it correct or not.

```
-(void)mySearchMethod
{
NSArray *allObjects = self.allMyObjects;
__block NSMutableArray *searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


dispatch_queue_t queue;
queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_async( queue, ^{


    for (MyObjectClass *myObjectAsDictionary in allObjects) {

        for (NSString *titleSubString in [myObjectAsDictionary.title componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]) {

            if ([[titleSubString lowercaseString] hasPrefix:[text lowercaseString]]) {
                [searchArray addObject: myObjectAsDictionary];

            }
        }
    }


    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.tableObjects = searchArray;
        [self.myTableView reloadData];


    });
});
}
```

So does this code work in the background, or is it blocking the main thread?

Answer (score 0):

Can the contents of `allMyObjects` change while the search is running?  If so, you have two problems.  First problem: you should not accessing an array on one thread while it's being mutated on another.  You can fix this simply by copying the array: `NSArray *allObjects = [self.allMyObjects copy];`.  Second problem: your search results might contain objects that have been removed from `allMyObjects`, or might be missing objects that have been added to `allMyObjects`.  This is a hard problem to solve and how you solve it depends on your app.

What happens if the user cancels the search before your async block finishes running?  Will it replace the contents of a table with search results even though the user doesn't want to see the results now?

Comment: No, the content of allMyObjects doesn't change while search is running. If user cancel the search, the normal state (all objects) will fill the table view. I don't test this search on large array with objects.